# How do I remove WordPress Shortcode Ultimate Accordion auto-open option on mobile using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I am currently using Wordpress Shortcode Ultimate's Accordion. The plugin already have the option to open the accordion on page load and I'm using that option now but I also want them to be closed on mobile.

How do I remove that option on mobile using jquery?

Here is their code:

```
$('body:not(.su-other-shortcodes-loaded)').on('click', '.su-spoiler-title', function (e) {
    var $title = $(this),
        $spoiler = $title.parent(),
        bar = ($('#wpadminbar').length > 0) ? 28 : 0;
    // Open/close spoiler
    $spoiler.toggleClass('su-spoiler-closed');
    // Close other spoilers in accordion
    $spoiler.parent('.su-accordion').children('.su-spoiler').not($spoiler).addClass('su-spoiler-closed');
    // Scroll in spoiler in accordion
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $title.offset().top) $(window).scrollTop($title.offset().top - $title.height() - bar);
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.su-spoiler-content').removeAttr('style');
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Detect device,

BY PHP:

you can check your website is loading on mobile device or desktop device by word press default functionality and apply condition for loading sort code

```
wp_is_mobile()
```

By jquery:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

Comment: please add description for wp_is_mobile

Comment: Thank you very much @ashpatel and vasimvanzara but what speicific CODE should I use to remove this option or to make my accordion closed on mobile. Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

I applied this code in my PHP footer of my theme and it is working!

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {    // Optional: if you want to detect when the window is resized;
        processBodies($(window).width());
    });
    function processBodies(width) {
        if(width < 768) {
            $('.su-spoiler').addClass('su-spoiler-closed');
        }
        else {
            $('.su-spoiler').addClass('default');
        }
    }
    processBodies($(window).width());
});
```